# setting up an SMS gateway

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

i have been asked to create a SMS Gateway Architecture. 
Basically i am a part of a team that maintains a Call Centre website and hence frequent SMS are to be sent(and received).

I have found out that "CALL MEDIA" and "CONNECTIVITY TERMINALS" are best ways to do such a task.
I have also been suggested that .NET framework has to be used as the gateway should be on WINDOWS platform.

Can anyone guide me how to even start with an architecture?

I am completely new to this subject matter and the thing is i couldn't get much help directly from the internet.

Answer (score 4):

I have installed http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/, which does what you are talking about, with a $20 USB modem hooked up to a server, then wrote a custom app that deals with moving the incoming/outgoing message queues into a database.

Comment: Do you have some time to share your experience?  What modem you used?  Where I can find one other than ebay?

Answer (score 0):

Sending and receiving SMS reliably is best handled by using a dedicated professional business SMS provider like Esendex (http://www.esendex.com).

You can integrate with your Call Centre website using the APIs available (http://www.esendex.co.uk/Developers) and it'll save you the headache of having to understand, host and implement your own custom SMS solution.

Also, SMS Gateways like Esendex have multiple, reliable connections to mobile phone networks around the world which means your messages will be handled more efficiently than you having to create links with SMS Providers yourself.

If there's any specific requirements or scenarios you're trying to address then feel free to comment and I'll try and advise to narrow your scope of enquiry. (Disclosure: I'm one of the development team at Esendex)

Sign up for a free trial and give it a go!

Comment: it's a serious suggestion/solution to avoid extra effort in reinventing the wheel. if there's a genuine reason why a local bespoke solution is required or necessary, I invited the poster to offer further information to narrow what was a very generic question to begin with. Sometimes knowing how others solve problems can be inspiration enough to spark creativity. I deliberately disclosed that I worked for the company mentioned but the approach to solving the problem remains valid, in my opinion.

Comment: Umm.. So if you were a developer for a web based marketing solution that an email server that serves emails for it's clients, it would seem right to go ahead and make our own sms gateway, right?

Comment: Some SMS Gateways can offer email as a way of integrating. Forwarding an email to an address like 0123456789@someSMSgateway.com would then deliver the content of the message to the mobile phone. Given you are email experts already then there's little point having to make your own sms gateway unless you have very specific reasons to do so.